# New activity record (startdate, enddate) without overlap in Standard SQL

Tags: sql

Memory table

```
startdate           enddate             activity
2015.07.01 19:00    2015.07.01 19:30    a
2015.07.01 19:30    2015.07.01 19:45    b
2015.07.02 15:00    2015.07.02 15:30    c
```

Restriction:

The time period of two activities shall not overlap each other, i.e. a new activity cannot be started before the other is ended.

A day cannot exceed 24 hours as the sum of the current day’s activity interval.

Thank you

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: When you add a new line, a record they do not overlap.

Comment: What application is used to enter records?

Comment: Old, written in Delphi. The data is stored TSQLMemTable.

Comment: select sum(cnt)
from 
(
select count(*) as cnt from EmploymentHistory where '2015-07-01 20:01:00'  >= StartDate and '2015-07-01 20:01:00'  <= EndDate -- StartDate
union all
select count(*) as cnt from EmploymentHistory where '2015-07-01 21:55:00'  >= StartDate and '2015-07-01 21:55:00'  <= EndDate -- EndDate
union all
select count(*) as cnt from EmploymentHistory where  '2015-07-01 20:01:00'  between startdate and enddate and '2015-07-01 21:55:00' between startdate and enddate -- StartDate && EndDate
) x;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two date ranges overlap if and only if the start of each range is before the end of the other range. i.e.

```
(Start1, End1) overlaps (Start2, End2)
if and only if
Start1 < End2 && Start2 < End1
```

You can write a query around this check without being too cumbersome.